# debugging macro related errors on QNX

Tags: c, gcc, qnx

I am trying to complile one project on QNX which uses libxml. I have installed libxml on system with support for xmlschema turned on. But still I get below error message 
'xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)

On going thorough libxml source I found that xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr definitions is protected by LIBXML_SCHEMAN_ENABLED macro which gets defined in xmlversion.h as

```
#if 1
#define LIBXML_SCHEMAS_ENABLED
#endif
```

Now how to see weather this macro is actually getting defined in qnx preprocessing step or not. I tried -P option but it is not printing any macro definitions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I tried -P option but it is not printing any macro definitions.

Options `-dD -E` are helpful in such cases.